# Glassfish v21 - is there a way to customize admin console login page per domain?

Tags: dns, glassfish, administration

I have two to three domains under a single glassfish installation.
Is there a known way to customize admin console login page based on the domain I am trying to administrator? (host/port)

Comment: I have the same problem. I'd like to make it very clear which console is the production server and which one is testing. At 2 in the morning, sometimes mistakes happen.

Comment: @Preston. I found a way just to change the login page image. There is a png file LoginProductName.png in your <app server install root>\lib\install\applications\admingui\adminGUI_war\WEB-INF\lib\admin-jsf.jar -> \images\ folder. You can replace it with whatever image you like and next time you go to admin console, you will have a different image for your admin console login page. This will work in a scenario when you have just 1 domain 1 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firefox or Chrome as your browser then you could write a Greasemonkey script that would change the page's appearance for each admin console. It should be fairly trivial and there are lots of examples out there that you should be able to copy.

Comment: cool idea! though not exactly what I was looking for. But better change client side than to touch bundled software in prod. cool!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your hint to Preston, I was able to change the banner image across the top.  That file is lib\install\applications\admingui\adminGUI_war\WEB-INF\lib\webui-jsf-suntheme.jar\com\sun\webui\jsf\suntheme\images\masthead\masthead-background.jpg.

Originally that file was a one-pixel wide gradient, but changed it to a 200 pixel wide image with the same height and it worked fine.